# Get pressed key in linux C

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to recognize the key pressed by the user. I wan't the program to stop if the user is pressing an 'UP' key. I'm doing this for a further command history implementation. This `getKey()` code is not my function, I found it here somewhere, should it work ? Because whenever I press the 'UP' key nothing happens.

```
int getKey(){
int character;
struct termios orig_term_attr;
struct termios new_term_attr;

tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &orig_term_attr);
memcpy(&new_term_attr, &orig_term_attr, sizeof(struct termios));
new_term_attr.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ICANON);
new_term_attr.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
new_term_attr.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &new_term_attr);

character = fgetc(stdin);

tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &orig_term_attr);

return character;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

char cmd[500];
int key;

do{
    printf("$ > ");
    fgets(cmd, 499, stdin);
    trim(cmd);
    key = getKey();

    if(key == 0x17C){
        break;
    }

    if(starts_with(cmd, "./")){
        execute_external_command(cmd);
    }else{
        execute_internal_command(cmd);
    }


}while(strcmp(cmd, "exit") != 0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you take the time to understand what the function does and whether it does it correctly? Aren't you interested in learning?

Comment: I'm not that interested in C, but I do have a school project, so I need to do this.

Comment: I am very sorry for you if you are not interested in the most beautiful and powerful language of all. It's like not being interested in learning english if you are not native english speaker.

Answer (score 2):

It is tricky. You should read about `tty`-s, notably the [TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/). Understand the role of the kernel in [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline).

I suggest using the [GNU readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) (it has history and autocompletion functions!) or the [GNU ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library (otherwise, if running a GUI application under X11, code in [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/)). Otherwise, dive into books (e.g. [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)) explaining the details of tty (and its raw & cooked modes), and see [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) & [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) for a start.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think GNU readline implements a history which is what the OP wants.

Comment: Tha't why I said "yes"